# How to find unique values based on two column using awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, unique

Consider I have a test file (test.txt)contains data as

```
1,2 
2,3 
2,1 
2,2 
3,1 
1,3 
2,5
4,1
```

I want the remove duplicates per pair, say for pair (1,2) and (2,1) either of one should be printed (First come first print). Expected output is

```
1,2
2,3
3,1
2,2
2,5
4,1
```

I have tried this command, `awk -F"," '!seen[$1,$2]++ && !seen[$2,$1]' test.txt`.It prints as

```
1,2
2,3
3,1
2,5
4,1
```

Why the pair 2,2 is not printing? Also how to get the expected output.

Comment: `awk` has "seen" first `2` in `2,3`, hence `2,2`  is omitted.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Got it. How can i get the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated, the problem comes from short-circuiting in the logical evaluation.

To circumvent this, one option is to test and set one single value in the 2D-table `seen` :

```
awk -F"," '!seen[($1<$2?$1:$2)+0, ($1>$2?$1:$2)+0]++'
```

Basically it uses the minimum and the maximum of the two values as indexes, hence one single test instead of two, and then increment the slot.

Note the `+0` instruction which forces casting into integers. This have to be done because fields enclose extra whitespaces including final end-of-line.

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks. Just curious, If i the input has 3 columns, we need to put multiple conditional check?

Comment: In a more general case, I would use [`asort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html) to sort values first, then use the (sorted) values as indexes.

Answer (score 1):

The common, idiomatic 2-field solution with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ awk -F, '!seen[$1>$2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1]++' file
1,2
2,3
2,2
3,1
2,5
4,1
```

and for any number of fields using GNU awk for `asort()`:

```
awk -F, '{split($0,a); asort(a); for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) k=(i>1 ? k FS : "") a[i]} !seen[k]++' file
```

e.g. for an input file containing every permutation of 1,2,3 and 2,3,4:

```
$ cat file
1,2,3
1,3,2
2,1,3
2,3,1
3,1,2
3,2,1
2,3,4
2,4,3
3,2,4
3,4,2
4,2,3
4,3,2

$ awk -F, '{split($0,a); asort(a); for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) k=(i>1 ? k FS : "") a[i]} !seen[k]++' file
1,2,3
2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no good in `awk`, but that's rally easy to do using other tools.

If the order doesn't matter, let's duplicate each line with order reversed. Then we can just use `sort -u` to print unique lines:

```
cat <<EOF |
1,2
2,3
2,1
2,2
3,1
1,3
2,5
4,1
EOF
sed 's/\(.*\),\(.*\)/\1,\2:\1,\2\n\2,\1:\1,\2/' | 
sort -u -t: -k1,1 |
cut -d: -f2 |
sort -u
```

The `sed` utlity transform the line:

```
 1,2
```

into:

```
 1,2:1,2
 2,1:1,2
```

Then I remove duplicates using the first column only separated by `:` with `sort -u -t: -k1,1`. Then `cut -d: -f2` to removes the first column. Then I sort unique lines again, because we will have duplicates (ex. when `1,2` is unique for both `1,2` and `2,1`). The result is:

```
1,2
2,2
2,3
2,5
3,1
4,1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order is not important, you could use the **awk**, **sort** and **uniq** combination easily.

```
awk -F "," '$1 < $2 { printf "%d,%d\n", $1,$2} $2 <= $1 {printf "%d,%d\n", $2, $1}' file | sort | uniq
```

The awk actions here normalize the output by sorting the numbers so `2,1` will become `1,2`